# User profile not updating in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, profile-sync, ad

We have a SharePoint 2013 environment and we use SharePoint Active Directory Import for User profile synchronization. We have the connections setup for different domains and the timer job “User Profile Service Application - User Profile Active Directory Import Job” runs every 5 mins.

The issue I am having is one of the user information got updated in AD but that is not getting reflected in Manage User Profiles page of central admin. It is pulling all new users from AD to User Profile. We have only User Profile Service running on our User profile server and not User Profile Synchronization service(mysite is disabled). Is there something that I am missing. Can I do a force AD import for just one user using powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally AD changes on SharePoint take from 8 to 10 hours to take effect

after that if you are experiencing the same problem probably you will be having a cache issue

fist review if you are importing the whole active directory, 
if not, try to configure the whole AD to import (include all OUs)

Then delete that specific user profile and start a new sync, the new user will be added back, if still is not filling the latest data then you'll have to wait for the cache to refresh or manually provoke it.

one easy way to clear the cache is by restarting the server

Comment: Thanks for your response. It has been few days so I think AD changes should have been applied. I am importing the domain to which this user belongs and also I can see the user profile for that user it's just that it is not getting updated with the latest changes. I have tried restarting the server too.

When you say delete that specific user profile and start a new sync does it mean Full or incremental?

Comment: you can do that, also you can single import from powershell 
Set-SPUser and send the -SyncFromAD parameter